# c# error with calling async method - "Could not load type '<deleteCommands>d__2' from assembly

Tags: c#, webrequest

So, I'm really a PHP developer, so no doubt this is a really obvious thing I'm missing.

I seem to be having problem with running async methods - I've tried a couple of ways (using await, using a Task), and I keep getting the above error whenever calling a method that is async..

The function as it stands currently is ...

```
    public async static void deleteCommands(List<int> commandIds)
    {

        Tebex.logWarning("Async Delete....");
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            String url = "http://www.example.com/" + "queue?";
            String amp = "";

            foreach (int CommandId in commandIds)
            {
                url = url + amp + "ids[]=" + CommandId;
                amp = "&";
            }

            Tebex.logWarning("DELETE " + url);

            var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "DELETE";
            request.Headers.Add("APIKey", "myApiKey");
            var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
            Tebex.logWarning(response.ToString());
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);

    }
```

and I'm calling it from another method (I don't need the response or anything, it's a fire-and-forget method)

```
                try
                {
                    deleteCommands(executedCommands);
                    executedCommands.Clear();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Tebex.logError(ex.ToString());
                }
```

Previously I was using `await request.getResponseAsync()` but I received the same error -

```
    public async static void deleteCommands(List<int> commandIds)
    {

        Tebex.logWarning("Async Delete....");

        String url = "http://www.example.com/" + "queue?";
        String amp = "";

        foreach (int CommandId in commandIds)
        {
            url = url + amp + "ids[]=" + CommandId;
            amp = "&";
        }

        Tebex.logWarning("DELETE " + url);

        var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "DELETE";
        request.Headers.Add("APIKey", "myApiKey");
        await request.GetResponseAsync();

        request = null;

    }
```

As I mentioned, I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't figure out what!

Comment: You really should `await` the call to `deleteCommands`. Also the Task.Run should probably be removed again (no need to force a new thread, right?). If you really want a new thread, you should call the method using Task.Run instead. I assume WebRequest has some async overloads too, but you seem to be using it sync.

Comment: Yes, I had tried that originally (added more details to question), but I get the same error using GetResponseAsync without the Task

Comment: you should always return a `Task` from an async method.

Answer (score 2):

*I'm not sure if any of this resolves your exception, but it should be changed regardless.*

Instead of returning `void` you should return `Task` from *deleteCommands*. More on that here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Depending on how your calling method looks, and how you'd like thread-management to function, there are a couple of solutions:

The preferred:

```
await deleteCommands(executedCommands);
```

This requires a `async` method though.

If you really want to use `Task.Run` (forces a new thread. Considder the load), then use it when calling the method **instead**:

```
Task.Run(async () => await deleteCommands(executedCommands));
```

Additionaly if you have an async method it, and all following calls, should also follow the async pattern. Switch to async *WebRequests* and use an async logger.

Comment: It does remove the exception, however it then just stops execution at that point - no additional logging. I don't doubt your answer is correct, but something this side means it's not playing ball....

For now I've put it in a thread - this is POC code so I'll get someone who knows what they are doing to look at it later :)

Comment: Feel free to edit the original post with the new code if you want a second  opinion, or explain what changes you've made :)

Comment: I have a feeling it's either something to do with Unity or the game I'm specifically writing code for, since I've written basically the exact same code before (using async/await) and it worked fine, but I'll come back to it at some point no doubt :)

Comment: sure, calling an async method synchronously will work, but what's the point. A bit of extra overhead for no gain. Also `awaiting` the call would make things happen in the correct order, hence making Aman's answer not needed (but it was a good idea for the original code!). Best of luck to you!

Answer (score 2):

You should not clear the executedCommands list immediately because it is a fire and forget method (list can be cleared before the method finishes execution)

You should use ContinueWith instead

```
deleteCommands(executedCommands)
.ContinueWith(r => executedCommands.Clear());
```